# writing a custom logic in admin.py for prepopulated fields value in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I have a model - Comment to which I have added a slug field.

```
class Comment(Model):
    on_blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    commentor = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
```

In the corresponding CreateView.form_valid() I have added a logic to populated the slug field so that every time a user comments an appropriate slug is created:

```
form.instance.slug = slugify(f"{form.instance.commentor.username}-{slugify(form.instance.content[:50])}-{utils.get_random_alphanumeric()}")
```

My goal is to write a similar logic in admin.py for prepopulated fields. How to achieve that? I am already aware of the fact that prepopulated fields do not use foreign key fields, datefields, etc so I would not be able to include the commentor in custom logic. But I would want to add rest of fields into the logic of building up the slug value i.e content and utils.get_random_alphanumeric().

Thanks!

Comment: Please share modelform class code. Are you using generic view CreateView in ModelAdmin class?